# ReactJS - Is it possible to prevent/exclude a column from being sorted?

Tags: reactjs, npm, datatable, frontend, jsx

I am new in ReactJS and currently creating a project that uses a Data Table library that I got from here: 
[react-data-table-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component)

What I am trying to do is to exclude or prevent the first column from being re-arranged/re-sorted WHEN other columns has been clicked to sort.

Here's my current Data Table:

[image]

I am trying to achieve this to prevent the re-ordering the row number or index number, so whatever the column has been sorted, the first column will be in Ascending Order (from 1 to n).

If this is not possible then what other approach may I take to make the ranking column be always in ASCENDING order regardless of what column (Except the ranking column) has been sorted?

Here's my entire code for the component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

const CountryTable = ({items}) => {
    
var x=0;
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    items[i].index = i;
}

console.log(items);

return(
    <DataTable
        title="Covid-19 Stats"
        defaultSortAsc="false"
        responsive
        defaultSortField="cases"
        defaultSortAsc={false}
        striped
        highlightOnHover
        columns={
            [
                {
                    name: '#',
                    selector: 'index',
                    disableSortBy: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Country',
                    selector: 'country',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Total Cases',
                    selector: 'cases',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Additional New Cases',
                    selector: 'todayCases',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Current Active Cases',
                    selector: 'active',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Total Deaths',
                    selector: 'deaths',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Additional New Deaths',
                    selector: 'todayDeaths',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Total Recoveries',
                    selector: 'recovered',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Additional New Recoveries',
                    selector: 'todayRecovered',
                    sortable: true,
                },
            ]
        }
        keyField={items.index}
        data={items}
    />  
);
}

export default CountryTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `selector` attribute to provide a custom value to be rendered. In this case, an `index` could be used (probably you'll need `index+1`).

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

const CountryTable = ({items}) => {
    
var x=0;
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    items[i].index = i;
}

console.log(items);

return(
    <DataTable
        title="Covid-19 Stats"
        defaultSortAsc="false"
        responsive
        defaultSortField="cases"
        defaultSortAsc={false}
        striped
        highlightOnHover
        columns={
            [
                {
                    name: '#',
                    selector: (row, index) => index,
                    sortable: false,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Country',
                    selector: 'country',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Total Cases',
                    selector: 'cases',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Additional New Cases',
                    selector: 'todayCases',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Current Active Cases',
                    selector: 'active',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Total Deaths',
                    selector: 'deaths',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Additional New Deaths',
                    selector: 'todayDeaths',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Total Recoveries',
                    selector: 'recovered',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Additional New Recoveries',
                    selector: 'todayRecovered',
                    sortable: true,
                },
            ]
        }
        keyField={items.index}
        data={items}
    />  
);
}

export default CountryTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the note regarding index+1 :) And I can now remove the loop for adding a property on object. It saved me few lines of code and time. Thank you!